# Calling yeoman generator from python?

Tags: python, django, yeoman, popen

I need to call this generator via python in a webapp I've been working on. Originally I did this by piping yes to the generator but I need to say no to the first option.

```
yes | yo angular --no-insight
```

Now I am sending the output of a file to the generator to tell it to enter

```
cat input.txt | yo angular --no-insight
```

input.txt

```
n
y
y
```

This works just fine, but I also need to store the logs so I redirect the output to out.txt

```
cat input.txt | yo angular --no-insight > out.txt
```

This is where things go wrong, the first prompt is answered with a no as I would expect, then everything just stops.

I need a way to programatically run the generator, I thought that using an Adaptor would be the solution, but there seems to be absolutely no documentation for writing one.

What should I do to fit my use case?

Edit: Here is my popen call I already use to run the command

```
        Popen("cat input.txt | yo angular --no-insight", shell=True).wait()
```

The class that runs the command is on its own thread so the waiting for several minutes is not a problem. However I will probably be removing that in a future update to handle timeouts of generators should anything go wrong.

Comment: What happens if you run `<input.txt yo angular --no-insight >out.txt` from the command-line? (Does it work?) How do you run the command in Python? (show the code)

Comment: Same thing happens, the first prompt is answered with no and then no other input is passed. The post has been updated to include my popen call.

Comment: Have you tried to redirect stderr too? In bash: `&> out.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Can you use python's [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as file_output:
    file_output.write(subprocess.check_output('cat input.txt | yo angular --no-insight', shell=True))
```

You can also just create a `Popen` object to 'yo angular --no-insight' and write to stdin and read from stdout.

Comment: to redirect subprocess' output to a file, use `check_call(cmd, stdout=file_output)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, using the file_output.write() solution gave the same result, the first line of my input gets passed in and then no further input goes through. I neglected to mention that I was using subprocess already. I'll play more with using Popens stdin and stdout redirects to get this working.